# Valgrind Error for Eratosthenes Prime (C)

Tags: c, valgrind

I've written this program to calculate the prime numbers up to `len` using Eratosthenes method. The program works fine and I can even calculate up to very large numbers like 999,999 and so on and I get a fine output. But the issue is that valgrind always shows me errors, no matter how small or how big `len` is.

### Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    size_t len=100;
    int *array=malloc(len * sizeof(*array));

    // initialize all elements to 1
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        array[i]=1; 

    //set multiples of array[a] to 0
    for(int a=2;a<len;a++){
        for(int b=2;b<len;b++){
            if(a*b>len)
                break;
            array[a*b]=0;
        }
    }

    //print the index of "1"s in the array
    for(int a=2;a<=len;a++){
        if(array[a]==1)
            printf("%d ", a);
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

### Errors:

I compile using: `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -g test.c -o test`
Output: `2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97`
`gdb` shows no errors or malfunction
`valgrind ./test` shows:

```
==10134== Invalid write of size 4
==10134==    at 0x400695: main (...)
==10134==  Address 0x52041d0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 400 alloc'd
==10134==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (...)
==10134==    by 0x400625: main (...)
==10134== 
==10134== Invalid read of size 4
==10134==    at 0x4006D9: main (...)
==10134==  Address 0x52041d0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 400 alloc'd
==10134==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (...)
==10134==    by 0x400625: main (...)
==10134== 
 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97 
==10134== 
==10134== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10134==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10134==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,424 bytes allocated
==10134== 
==10134== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==10134== 
==10134== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10134== ERROR SUMMARY: 8 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

As you can see in the code, I am declaring my array as `int *array=malloc(len * sizeof(*array));` which *seems to me* to be the problem. If I declare it like this: `int array[len];`, valgrind doesn't show me error for small numbers of `len`, which is also something that fascinates me. Higher numbers of `len` with VLA declaration causes some unexpected behavior. So what is happening here? Is there anything wrong with the code or can I simply ignore the valgrind errors, since the output is ok? Also, as I said earlier, the program works fine for very large numbers like 999,999 but running valgrind for that `len` gives exactly 999,999 errors in valgrind. Any explanation is highly appreciated :)

Comment: `for(int a=2;a<=len;a++)` overflows `array` because `array[len-1]` is the last element in the array, It should be `for(int a=2;a<len;a++)`

Comment: If you declare a local array without malloc, you need to hardcode the size of the array with a constant.  Failure to do so is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks you are right, I changed that, now it is showing 7 errors instead of 8 :D

Comment: Since you have `if(a*b>len)
                break;
            array[a*b]=0;`, you will write to `array[100]` on occasion, but that is not in bounds.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler when would that happen? The `break` breaks the inner loop, for all consequent `b` that would be case.

Comment: @Pablo: The first time would be `a == 2` and `b == 50`; `a * b == 100`, which is not greater than `len`, so `array[100]` would be written — which is out of bounds.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler of course. I didn't catch that the first time reading the code, shame on me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `malloc` is correct, `sizeof(*array)` is the same as `sizeof(int)`, because `*array` is an `int`.

`for(int a=2;a<=len;a++)` overflows `array` because `array[len-1]` is the last element in the array and eventually you do

```
if(array[a]==1)
   printf("%d ", a);
```

with `a==100` which is out of bounds.

It should be

```
for(int a=2;a<len;a++)
    if(array[a] == 1)
        printf("%d ", a);
```

**Edit**

As [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957989/valgrind-error-for-eratosthenes-prime-c#comment84923010_48957989) has pointed out in the comments,

```
if(a*b>len)
    break;
```

if also wrong. For `a==2` and `b==50` you have `a*b==100` which is not greater
than `len` and you are accessing out of bounds again. The condition should be

```
if(a*b >= len)
    break;
```

Comment: Thanks Pablo, that definitely fixed one of the errors that I didn't predict. I still have another `Invalid write of size 4` in the valgrind output though.

Comment: @NightWish: see [comment 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957989/valgrind-error-for-eratosthenes-prime-c#comment84923010_48957989) and [comment 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957989/valgrind-error-for-eratosthenes-prime-c#comment84923099_48957989).

Comment: Wow thanks a lot!!!! Didn't think it would be so simple but I understand now, the issue was exactly as you said `if(a*b > len-1)`!! I appreciate it!!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you for the edit, I prefer the `>=` too, which makes more sense to me. Have a great day everyone! :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for fixing my answer, if you think that this version is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Just two comments about your code:

The algorithm implemented here is not exactly the algorithm known as *The sieve of Erathostenes*, because if you analyse your code you'll see that you have two loops, running all possible values of `a` and `b` and marking them as compound.  Yes, you finish with a sieve... but that was not the efficient one from Erathostenes.  The sieve of Erathostenes consists in getting the next unmarked element, and mark all elements that are multiples of it (until you reach the maximum index, at len) this is something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10000
#define sqrt_N 100

int array[N];

int main(){

    int a, b;
    /* better to leave them at 0 and marking with ones */
    // initialize all elements to 1
    //for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        //array[i]=1; 

    //set multiples of a to 1
    /* We only need to do this upto sqrt_N because if a unmarked number
     * is discovered above sqrt_N it will be marked (as compund) because
     * it was the product of a number less than sqrt_N or be prime (because
     * it cannot be the product of two numbers greater than the sqrt(N)
     * or it would be greater than N. */
    for(a = 2; a < sqrt_N; a++){
        if (array[a] == 0) { /* do the inner loop only if a is a prime */
            for(b = 2; a * b < N; b++)
                array[a * b] = 1;
        }
    }

    //print the index of "0"s in the array
    for(a = 2; a <= N; a++){
        if(!array[a])
            printf("%s%d", a == 2 ? "" : ", ", a);
    }

    printf("\n");

    //free(array); /* array is no more dynamic */
    return 0;
}
```

just check the computation time and you'll see it runs faster than yours.

The problem you are having with a declaration like this:

```
int sieve[999999];
```

is that, if you put that as a local variable on `main()` (as you do) it is going to be stored in the stack, so that means you need at least one million integers (of size 4, most probably) and this is four megabytes in the stack.  I don't actually know the operating system you are using, but it is common that the stack size is limited (in the order of 4-10 Mb) so you can overflow the stack if you are not careful with the size of your automatic variables.

The invalid write message from `valgrind(1)` comes from the fact that you have written the following code:

```
if (a*b > len) break;
```

and that means that, in the possible case that `a*b` results exactly `len`, you are writing in the array cell `array[len]` which is outside of the bounds of `array` (by one, they go from `0` to `len - 1`)  You have to change that line to read:

```
if (a*b >= len) break;
```

or

```
if (a*b < len) {
    array[a*b] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the awesome explanation, your program is unbelievably fast! If I wanted to check primes up to another numbers, I also have to define the `sqrt_N` manually? And another question, the program shows all primes up to `N`, but it also shows the `N` itself, in this example `10000`, which is not a prime. How do I fix that, since I don't understand this ternary operator `a == 2 ? "" : ", ", a`

Comment: Oh never mind, I figured it out after working on the code for a while! :)